# How to structure SQL tables with one (non-composite) candidate key and all non-primary attributes?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I'm not very familiar with relational databases but here is my question.

I have some raw data that's collected as a result of a customer survey. For each customer who participated, there is only one record and that's uniquely identifiable by the CustomerId attribute. All other attributes I believe fall under the non-prime key description as no other attribute depends on another, apart from the non-composite candidate key. Also, all columns are atomic, as in, none can be split into multiple columns.

For example, the columns are like CustomerId(non-sequential), Race, Weight, Height, Salary, EducationLevel, JobFunction, NumberOfCars, NumberOfChildren, MaritalStatus, GeneralHealth, MentalHealth and I have 100+ columns like this in total.

So, as far as I understand we can't talk about any form of normalization for this kind of dataset, am I correct?

However, given the excessive number of columns, if I wanted to split this monolithic table into tables with fewer columns, ie based on some categorisation of columns like demographics, health, employment etc, is there a specific name for such a structure/approach in the literature? All the tables are still going to be using the CustomerId as their primary key.

Yes, this is part of an assignment and as part of a task, it's required to fit this dataset into a relational DB, not a document DB which I don't think would gain anything in this case anyway.

So, there is no direct question as such as I worded above but creating a table with 100+ columns doesn't feel right to me. Therefore, what I am trying to understand is how the theory approaches such blobs. Some concept names or potential ideas for further investigation would be appreciated as I even don't know how to look this up.

Comment: The partition of columns in several relations can be reasonable if they are mostly used separately. If, on the other hand, you use them all together (or you use a good part of them.), it has no sense, since the join query can be more costly then a simple query.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insight. I don't expect to be accessing these columns all at the same time, so, using joins would be a very rare use case. By the way, do you happen to know any formal name for such grouping based on logical/functional similarity? I'd like to back my decisions with literature where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relational databases using all information in a table is not a good usage.
As you mentioned groping some columns in other tables and join all tables with master table is well. In this usage you can also manage one to many, many to one  and many to many relationships. Such as  customers could have more than one address or phone numbers.

An other usage is making a table like customer_properities and use  columns like property_type and property_value and store data by rows.
But the first usage is more effective and most common usage

```
customer_id  property_type   properity_value
1            num_of_child     3
1            age              22
1            marial_status    Single
.
.
.
```